# What is a "trusted server environment" in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

"Trusted" and "Privileged" server environments are frequently mentioned in the docs for Firebase, but there's no formal definition.  What are they?

How do I make my server trusted or privileged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what "priveleged" or "trusted" server environments are is not explicitly searchable (prior to the creation of this Q&A), it can be inferred from the following excepts.

In the docs for [FCM setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#firebase-admin-sdk-for-fcm), is the following excerpt:

> The server side of Firebase Cloud Messaging consists of two components:
>
> - The FCM backend provided by Google.
> - Your app server or other trusted server environment where your server logic runs, such as Cloud Functions for Firebase or other cloud environments managed by Google.
>
> Your app server or trusted server environment sends message requests to the FCM backend, which then routes messages to client apps running on users' devices.

And in the docs for [general setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/#initialize_the_sdk):

> Firebase projects support Google service accounts, which you can use to call Firebase server APIs from your app server or trusted environment. If you're developing code locally or deploying your application on-premises, you can use credentials obtained via this service account to authorize server requests.

1. Important to notice is that both explicitly say `"app server or trusted environment"` which implies the two are different things.
2. Further, the first excerpt (though somewhat semantically ambiguous)
   that examples of trusted environments are `"Cloud Functions for Firebase or other cloud environments managed by Google."`
3. Finally,
   in the second excerpt is the information `"If you're developing code locally or deploying your application on-premises, you can use credentials obtained via this service account to authorize server requests"`

From all of this it can be inferred that:

- **Trusted and Priveleged Environments** are generally things internal to google and therefore intrinsically trustworthy
- **App servers** are generally anything which has access to the right credentials
- And finally, you do not need to take any steps beyond having the correct credentials to make your server a "Trusted Environment." It does not need to be a "Trusted Environment," because what that term really means is "Owned by Google."

Answer (score 0):

A trusted environment is an environment where you control what code runs on it. In the context of apps built using Firebase, this sets them apart from the devices your regular app runs on as malicious users can take your app configuration data and run their own code with that.

I often explain trusted environment, as:

1. Your development machine, since you're usually the only one working on that.
2. A server (or VM, container, etc) that you control. Only you (and people you trust) should have access to the server, so shared servers are not a good fit.
3. Cloud Functions, since only collaborators on your Firebase project can deploy code there.

Comment: What makes my development machine "trusted" vs some third party machine?

Comment: The fact that you are signed in to it. I list it first because most code gets run on your own dev box first, and that is fine since it's *your* dev box.

Comment: How would Firebase know which server I am or am not signed into?

Comment: From trusted environments, you're typically using a Firebase Admin SDK, which is initialized with your credentials: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup. If you're not using an Admin SDK, you accomplish the same, you'll just have to handle the authentication yourself.