# Why are Cloud Functions not stopped from writing when using Security rules in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Cloud Firestore as my back-end. I'm using rules so only authenticated users can read some data (private data) and none of them can write. I have also created a function that is triggered when some new content is added to the database. However, when the function is triggered, I'm able to write data even if the rules as set to `false`.

How to stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you access to Firestore via a Cloud Function (using the Firebase Admin SDK) none of the security rules apply.

The following documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup explicitly indicates that for the Relatime Database:

> The Admin SDK lets you interact with Firebase from privileged
>   environments to perform actions like Read and write Realtime Database
>   data with full admin privileges.

but it is the same with Firestore.

There is also a note in this Firestore "Get Started" documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started:

> Note: The server client libraries bypass all Cloud Firestore Security
>   Rules...

As said above, this not only applies to the Admin SDK but also applies to the other server SDKs, because you use these server SDKs from what Firebase calls "a privileged environment", like your own server (under your control) or Cloud Functions (under your control too, since you are the only one able to deploy Cloud Functions code). See also [What is a "trusted server environment" in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008898/what-is-a-trusted-server-environment-in-firebase)

---

If you want to restrict the write access for your Cloud Function, you will need to develop a specific business logic, in your Cloud Function, to mimic your security rules.